# AngularJS post process links

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a laravel app that spits out the default pagination, however it adds "page" to every link and ignores what is currently in the query string. This is not a laravel question though just want to explain the issue.

Basically I need to add some sort of handler for the pagination links. The rest of the query string is handled via controls I made by creating a directive, so they are easily accessible. Through the controller I can easily create the "proper" url however I want to figure out the best way to do it.

I hear a lot that doing anything with the DOM itself is best avoided in angularJS because its not jQuery, so what is the best practice way to handle this issue in angularjs?

in jQuery I would do this.

```
jQuery('.pagination-wrap a').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var link = generateProperLink(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
   window.location.href = link;
});
```

But how would I do that in an angular controller (minus the obvious use jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use angular.element jqlite which is subset of jquery and it has most of the jquery methods u can use , refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

You can use directive for the reusable components

```
        <a id="someID" urlUsage><a> 

  //directive 

   App.directive('urlUsage',function(){

       var generateProperLink = function(ele){
             return ele.attr('href');
         }

         return {

             restrict: 'A',
             link:function(scope,ele,attrs) {

                     ele.on('click',function(){

                          event.preventDefault();
                           var link = generateProperLink(ele);
                             window.location.href = link;
                  })
              }

          }

    })
```

Comment: This seems like the best solution as if avoiding jQuery it can be done strictly through angular.

Comment: @JordanRamstad as mentioned angular uses the subset of jquery jqlite , where you can find most of the method , happy to help you :)

Comment: Agreed, it's a clean syntax, however, if jQuery is available, and loaded before Angular, jQuery gets used anyway.

Comment: I meant just in the interest of one less http request, extra libraries never really add much extra overhead in modern browsers (the good ones anyway) :).

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with using jQuery in AngularJS, you just need to let AngularJS know if it needs to do anything.  That could be as simple as a `$scope.$apply()` in the callback of jQuery event handler (or any non-angular construct), or something more complex, like compiling DOM changes in the context of a scope.

In your case, does angular need to know the "proper link"?  If not, you could wrap your code in an attribute directive.

*The following is illustrative, I haven't tested it*

```
(function(app, $) {

    app.directive('fixUrl', fixUrl);

    function fixUrl() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: link
        };

        function link(scope, element, attributes) {
            $(element).on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var link = generateProperLink(element);
                window.location.href = link;
            });
        }

        function generateProperLink(element){
            return $(element).attr('href');
        }
    }

}(angular.module('app'), jQuery));
```

Then...

```
<a class='pagination' fix-url>Whatever</a>
```

Comment: The problem is I don't have access to the generation of the pagination code, so I cannot adjust the url at runtime. Although the fact that you state its fine to use jquery is good enough for me. Thank you.